# Jedis and Redisson Client used together with a Redis Cluster

Tags: jedis, redisson

I have a requirement to develop some new feature in a given application which is currently using Jedis for redis operations.
I need to use Redis locks extensively for the new feature and redisson supports them very well.Can I use Redisson client with same redis cluster in my application or will it cause an issue?
The new flow is entirely different and there will be no interesction between operations through redisson and Jedis

regards
Ankit

Answer (score 5):

You can use Redisson along with Jedis with same Redis cluster in same application. This should not cause any problem.